# How to write a function in R to download files and gather the data?

Tags: r, function

There are the urls I have saved and I have saved the variable names into a vector.

```
gapminder 
if(!file.exists("./data")) {dir.create("./data")}
fileUrls <- c("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkBd6lyS3EmpdHo5S0J6ekhVOF9QaVhod05QSGV4T3c&output=xlsx",
         "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=phAwcNAVuyj2tPLxKvvnNPA&output=xlsx",
         "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=phAwcNAVuyj0XOoBL_n5tAQ&output=xlsx")
var_names <- c("GDP","life_expectancy", "population")
```

I want to fill in the function get_clean to download and read in the excel file from the url provided and then put the data in a column with the variable name specified in var_name.

```
get_clean <- function(url_in, var_name){

}
```

I can do it in separate code, but I don't know how to write them in a function.

Such as

```
life_expect_url <- fileUrls[[2]]
download.file(life_expect_url, destfile = "./data/tmp.xlsx", mode = "wb")
life_expect <-read_excel("./data/tmp.xlsx")
# change the name of the first variable to country
names(life_expect)[[1]] <- "country"
life_expect <- life_expect %>%
    gather(key = "year", 
           value = !!var_names[[2]], 
           -country, 
           na.rm = TRUE,
           convert = TRUE)
head(life_expect, n = 5)

pop_url <- fileUrls[[3]]
download.file(pop_url, destfile = "./data/tmp.xlsx", mode = "wb")
pop <-read_excel("./data/tmp.xlsx")
# change the name of the first variable to country
names(pop)[[1]] <- "country"
pop <- pop %>%
    gather(key = "year", 
           value = !!var_names[[3]], 
           -country, 
           na.rm = TRUE,
           convert = TRUE)
head(pop, n= 5)
```

I tried this

```
get_clean <- function(url_in, var_name){
     download.file(url_in, destfile = "./data/tmp.xlsx", mode = "wb")
     a <- read_excel("./data/tmp.xlsx")
     names(a)[[1]] <- "country"
     a <- a %>% 
       gather(key = "year",
              value = !!var_name, 
              -country, 
              na.rm = TRUE, 
              convert = TRUE) 
}
out1 <- get_clean(fileUrls[1],var_names[1])
head(out1)
```

Is that right?
Should I use for loop?

The result should be like this:

```
## # A tibble: 6 x 3
##   country     year      GDP
##   <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1 Algeria     1960   1280.3848       
## 2 Argentina   1960   5251.8768       
## 3 Australia   1960   9407.6851       
## 4 Austria     1960   7434.1837       
## 5 Bahamas     1960   11926.4610
```

Comment: possibly of interest: https://bbolker.github.io/mpha_2019

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't solve my problem, but maybe useful for my future study.

Answer (score 0):

In this way files will be dowloaded as temp files and the final result will be a list, which includes the three datasets.

```
fileUrls <- c("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AkBd6lyS3EmpdHo5S0J6ekhVOF9QaVhod05QSGV4T3c&output=xlsx",
              "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=phAwcNAVuyj2tPLxKvvnNPA&output=xlsx",
              "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=phAwcNAVuyj0XOoBL_n5tAQ&output=xlsx")
var_names <- c("GDP","life_expectancy", "population")


get_clean <- function(fileUrl, var_name){
  tmpfile <- rep(tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx"), length(fileUrl))
  lapply(1:length(fileUrl), function(x) {
    link <- fileUrl[x]
    file <- download.file(link, tmpfile[x])
    file <- readxl::read_excel(tmpfile[x])
    names(file)[1] <- "country"
    file <- file %>%
      tidyr::gather(year, !!rlang::sym(var_names[x]), -country, 
                    na.rm = TRUE, convert = TRUE)
    file
  })
}

l <- get_clean(fileUrls, var_names)
l[[1]]

[[1]]                                                                                                                     
# A tibble: 7,988 x 3
   country     year    GDP
   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Algeria     1960  1280.
 2 Argentina   1960  5252.
 3 Australia   1960  9408.
 4 Austria     1960  7434.
 5 Bahamas     1960 11926.
 6 Bangladesh  1960   255.
 7 Barbados    1960  3397.
 8 Belgium     1960  7455.
 9 Belize      1960   950.
10 Benin       1960   257.
# … with 7,978 more rows
```

If you want to keep files stored in a specific folder after download, you just need to change the part that builds the path:

```
get_clean <- function(fileUrl, var_name){
  filepath <- paste0("./data", var_name, filext = ".xlsx")
  lapply(1:length(fileUrl), function(x) {
    link <- fileUrl[x]
    file <- download.file(link, filepath[x])
    file <- readxl::read_excel(filepath[x])
    names(file)[1] <- "country"
    file <- file %>%
      tidyr::gather(year, !!rlang::sym(var_names[x]), -country, 
                    na.rm = TRUE, convert = TRUE)
    file
  })
}


l <- get_clean(fileUrls, var_names)
l[[1]]
```

Yes, you have to make a loop. But i suggest to not use a for loop. Instead, use a lapply. It's clean, faster (if correctly builded) and do not populate your environment and RAM with elements created inside loop.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did it in another way and I edit the question.

Comment: Hey @dayucpbx7! I have edited the answer too, including an example on how to make the function store the files in some folder. You are trying to make this using for loop, but lapply is much better for this situations. Take a look here if you want further examplanations: https://www.r-bloggers.com/for-loops-and-how-to-avoid-them/

Comment: And if this solves your problem, remember to mark as the correct answer :)